# Inheritance and Multiple Constructor

Tags: c++

Okay so I have this person class.

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include<string>

using namespace std;


class Person
{
protected:
string name;
int age;
public:
Person();
Person(string newname, int newage);
void SetName(string n);
void SetAGe(int a);
string GetName();
int GetAge();
};

#endif
```

And the following person.cpp file.

```
#include "Person.h"

Person::Person(string newname, int newage){

name = newname;
age = newage;
}
```

And this Employee.h and .cpp file

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H
#include<string>
#include "Person.h"
using namespace std;


class Employee : public Person
{
protected:
float payrate;
public:
//Member functions
Employee() : Person(){ payrate = 10; }; //Constructor
Employee(float newpay);  //Constructor

void SetPayrate(float p);
float GetPayrate{ return p; }

#endif
```

Here's the cpp I had forgotten

```
#include "Employee.h"


Employee::Employee(float pay) : Person()
{
payrate = pay;
}
```

And this is supposed to be able to use this line of code 
    Employee b("Jane", 21, 12.38);

To create an employee with the name Jane, age 21, and payrate of 12.38, but it says that there is no method of the matching arguments. Am I missing something basic? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Employee has no constructor `Employee(string, int, float)` so you can't call it.

Comment: Okay, but that is what the assignment is, I need to do it through inheritance. How do I do that? haha

Comment: You need to add an Employee constructor with that signature. `Employee(string, int, float)`

Comment: So... make a constructor for `Employee` that takes the requisite parameters and invoke the appropriate `Person` constructor in the base class initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Employee` class has two explicitly declared constructors:

```
Employee() : Person(){ payrate = 10; }; //Constructor
Employee(float newpay);  //Constructor
```

The compiler gives you a copy constructor. Given these, you can construct an `Employee` using one of the three constructors only.

```
Employee e1;          // OK. Uses the first constructor.
Employee e2(2.4f);    // OK. Uses the second constructor.
Employee e3(e2);      // OK. Uses the copy constructor
Employee e4 = e2;     // OK. Uses the copy constructor
```

Any other way of constructing an `Employee` is not allowed. If you want to construct an `Employee` using

```
Employee e5("Jane", 21, 21.38);
```

you have declare a constructor that can accept those as arguments. E.g.

```
Employee(std::string const& name, int age, float payrate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are not inherited, and the compiler won't create new constructors like this for you.

You didn't write a constructor `Employee(string, int, float)`, so you can't call it.

If you add one, then you can:

```
// in the Employee class
Employee(string newname, int newage, float newpayrate)
    : Person(newname, newage)
{
    payrate = newpayrate;
}
```

You can, of course, put it all on one line if you want.

You could also put the definition in Employee.cpp, if you want. (Either way works.)